# determine the smallest n for which an in the interval

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be defined by
$$ a_n = (-1)^{n+2} \left(\frac{90}{100}\right)^n.$$

Determine $N$ such that $a_n \in (0,\frac{2}{1000})$,

Comment: Do you mean $|a_n| \in (0,\frac{1}{100})$?

Comment: the task doesn't specify this

Comment: But it is an alternating sequence. It is going to be negative for all even terms...

Comment: (a) the sought N is a multiple of 7.
(b) the sought N is a multiple of 9.
(c) the sought N is a multiple of 11  one of these options needs to be chosen, but I'm interested in the approach to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(a_n)=\{\frac{9}{10},-\frac{81}{100},\frac{729}{1000},-\frac{6561}{10000},\frac{59049}{100000},-\frac{531441}{1000000},\ldots\}$$
There is no way to find an $N$ such that for $n\ge N$ we have $0<a_n<\frac{1}{100}$ because it is an alternating sequence.

If you mean $|a_n|<\frac{1}{100}$ then we solve the inequality
$$\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^n<\frac{1}{100}$$
$$n\log\frac{9}{10}<\log\frac{1}{100}$$
$$n\log\frac{10}{9}>\log 100\to n>43.7$$
So taking $N=44$ we have that for any $n\ge N$, $|a_n|<\frac{1}{100}$

Comment: n≥N this condition did not exist.It was added by the editor, it's not his fault. I wrote down the condition very poorly initially. So n≥N was not in the condition initially.   And so  I still got 45. Since (-1)^ (n+1) must be positive, we get  46 for (-1)  and 45 for (9/10) then the condition An>0 is satisfied. But I can't understand why 45 is the smallest n .Why not two or 12 or 43 ...or any other.I can't understand , imagine

Comment: I also don't quite understand why we solve the inequality on the side of an<1/100, but don't consider 0<an

Comment: @БорисДорис $|a_n>0|$ is obvious.

Comment: @БорисДорис  if you take $n=12$ or $n=43$ you get $(9/10)^{12}\approx 0.28$ and $(9/19)^{43}\approx 0.0108$ and both values are not smaller than $1/100$

Comment: please give me a similar example when two inequalities should be solved. how to act in this case.

Comment: @БорисДорис  Something like $1 <x+2<4$ means $x+2<4$ AND $x+2>1$. The first means $x<2$ the second $x>-1$ so the solution is $-1<x<2$